# Attempt to read property "image" on null

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, laravel-blade

Here is the code listed below

```
public function update(Request $request, string $id)
{

    // Information validation 
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
        'price' => 'required|numeric',
        'category_id' => 'required|numeric'
    ]);
    $menu = Menu::find($id);

    //Validate if a user upload image
    if($request->image){
        $request->validate([
            'image' => 'nullable|file|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg|max:5000'
        ]);
        if($menu->image != "noimage.png"){ 
            $imageName = $menu->image;
            unlink(public_path('menu_images').'/'. $imageName);
        }
        $imageName = date('mdYHis').uniqid().'.'.$request->image->extension();
        $request->image->move(public_path('menu_images'), $imageName); 
    } else {
        $imageName = $menu->image;
    }

    $menu->name = $request->name;
    $menu->price = $request->price;
    $menu->image = $imageName;
    $menu->description = $request->description;
    $menu->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $menu->save();
    $request->session()->flash('status', $request->name. ' is updated successfully');
    return redirect('/management/menu');
}
```

The error is being thrown after the else statement. What I am trying to do in this if else statement is if the image is being uploaded in the request and if the menu already has the image and it's not the default one to then delete it. And then I would move the new image to the menu_images file. And if there is no new image I would use the one already in existence. This last step is the one that seems to be throwing the issue? I am honestly really lost and would appreciate a solution along with an explanation! Thank you

Comment: `find` can return `null` (didn't find a record) ... you have to check for this before trying to use what is returned

Answer (score 0):

```
$menu = Menu::find($id);
```

retrieves the menu by id. Since `$menu->image` tells you that you cannot get the `image` of `null`, we know that `$menu` is `null`, therefore a menu of that id does not exist. You will need to look into what the value of id is and whether that exists in your system. Look into what should happen if a not existent menu id is to be updated, whether you need to insert it instead if it does not exist and you will also need to look into how it is being retrieved, whether you are connected to the correct database, etc.